# Transforming JSON with Circe

Tags: json, scala, circe

Suppose I have some JSON data like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "title": "example input",
        "someBoolean": false,
        "innerData":  {
            "innerString": "input inner string",
            "innerBoolean": true,
            "innerCollection": [1,2,3,4,5]
        },
        "collection": [6,7,8,9,0]
    }
}
```

And I want to flatten it a bit and transform or remove some fields, to get the following result:

```
{
    "data": {
        "ttl": "example input",
        "bool": false,
        "collection": [6,7,8,9,0],
        "innerCollection": [1,2,3,4,5]
    }
}
```

How can I do this with [Circe](https://github.com/circe/circe)?

(Note that I'm asking this as a FAQ since similar questions often come up in the [Circe Gitter channel](https://gitter.im/circe/circe). This specific example is from a [question](https://gitter.im/circe/circe?at=5d840085b9f8210ed5b69514) asked there yesterday.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've sometimes said that Circe is primarily a library for encoding and decoding JSON, not for transforming JSON values, and in general I'd recommend mapping to Scala types and then defining relationships between those (as Andriy Plokhotnyuk suggests [here](https://gitter.im/circe/circe?at=5d84805928c1df0ed6627a61)), but for many cases writing transformations with cursors works just fine, and in my view this kind of thing is one of them.

Here's how I'd implement this transformation:

```
import io.circe.{DecodingFailure, Json, JsonObject}
import io.circe.syntax._

def transform(in: Json): Either[DecodingFailure, Json] = {
  val someBoolean = in.hcursor.downField("data").downField("someBoolean")
  val innerData = someBoolean.delete.downField("innerData")

  for {
    boolean    <- someBoolean.as[Json]
    collection <- innerData.get[Json]("innerCollection")
    obj        <- innerData.delete.up.as[JsonObject]
  } yield Json.fromJsonObject(
    obj.add("boolean", boolean).add("collection", collection)
  )
}
```

And then:

```
val Right(json) = io.circe.jawn.parse(
  """{
    "data": {
      "title": "example input",
      "someBoolean": false,
      "innerData":  {
        "innerString": "input inner string",
        "innerBoolean": true,
        "innerCollection": [1,2,3]
      },
      "collection": [6,7,8]
    }
  }"""
)
```

And:

```
scala> transform(json)
res1: Either[io.circe.DecodingFailure,io.circe.Json] =
Right({
  "data" : {
    "title" : "example input",
    "collection" : [
      6,
      7,
      8
    ]
  },
  "boolean" : false,
  "collection" : [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ]
})
```

If you look at it the right way, our `transform` method kind of resembles a decoder, and we can actually write it as one (although I'd definitely recommend not making it implicit):

```
import io.circe.{Decoder, Json, JsonObject}
import io.circe.syntax._

val transformData: Decoder[Json] = { c =>
  val someBoolean = c.downField("data").downField("someBoolean")
  val innerData = someBoolean.delete.downField("innerData")

  (
    innerData.delete.up.as[JsonObject],
    someBoolean.as[Json],
    innerData.get[Json]("innerCollection")
  ).mapN(_.add("boolean", _).add("collection", _)).map(Json.fromJsonObject)
}
```

This can be convenient in some situations where you want to perform the transformation as part of a pipeline that expects a decoder:

```
scala> io.circe.jawn.decode(myJsonString)(transformData)
res2: Either[io.circe.Error,io.circe.Json] =
Right({
  "data" : {
    "title" : "example input",
    "collection" : [ ...
```

This is also potentially confusing, though, and I've thought about adding some kind of `Transformation` type to Circe that would encapsulate transformations like this without questionably repurposing the `Decoder` type class.

One nice thing about both the `transform` method and this decoder is that if the input data doesn't have the expected shape, the resulting error will include a history that points to the problem.